# Instagram authorize with invalid clientID

Tags: redirect, instagram-api, authorize

I'm working with an application that is using the instagram API. All works well.

Just one question. When I redirect the user to the instagrams' authorize uri, it will be redirected to our "redirect_uri" as expected. But when I use an invalid clientID (user can make type errors), the redirect shows the JSON output (oAuth exception). Why isn't redirected to our redirect (with the error as response) so we can show a nice "error" screen?

Sven.

Comment: How is it that your user is entering the client id? Isn't that specific to your account?

Comment: Not that it is important, but it is for an add-on. But also when it is for myself, the same problem is still there. The error should also be redirected to the given redirect url to 'catch' the error and handle it in a proper way (a nice error message on screen).